# Почему в Selenium find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME) не находит элементы, возвращая пустой список Python

Tags: python, парсер, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Не удается получить что либо при парсинге класса

```
from requests import Session
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


option = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
option.set_preference('dom.webdriver.enabled', False)
option.set_preference('dom.webnotifications_enabled', False)
option.set_preference('media.volume_scale', '0.0')
option.set_preference('general.useragent.override', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36')

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('https://nftcalendar.io/')

button = browser.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'flex flex-wrap')
print(button)
```

Comment: Добавьте sleep(3) для полной загрузке страницы, потом ищите элементы.

Comment: Если в имени класса есть пробелы, то это не один класс, а несколько. Поэтому замените пробелы точками. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70399040/problems-extracting-elements-by-class-names-with-selenium

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При переборе элементов используется цикл for.

Чтобы увидеть, пишется `.text`, но только если обращаетесь к одному елементу `find_element`.

Также у Вас неправильно указан селектор: Вы должны указать селектор, в котором имеется количество элементов, относящееся к конкретному "Классу".

ниже привел рабочий код, протестируйте:

```
from requests import Session
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager


browser = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
browser.get('https://nftcalendar.io/')
button = browser.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='flex flex-wrap']/div")

for i in button:
    print(i.text)

browser.quit()
```